# Is it possible to pass Vimeo player variables through a jQuery function with dynamic hrefs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, fancybox, vimeo

```
I have links with vimeo urls in them:

    <a class="video" href="http://vimeo.com/9532951">link 1</a>
    <a class="video" href="http://vimeo.com/8228482">link 2</a>

Then I have manual fancybox call that loads the video into a fancybox:

    <script>
 $("a.video").click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
   'padding'  : 0,
   'autoScale'  : false,
   'transitionIn' : 'none',
   'transitionOut' : 'none',
   'title'   : this.title,
   'width'   : 400,
   'height'  : 265,
   'href'   : this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1'),
   'type'   : 'swf'
  });

  return false;
 });
</script>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pass arguments to the video player...autoplay=1 or fullscreen=1 etc etc etc.  I've tried a couple of things but nothing has worked.  Was thinking it was something like adding `'swf' : 'autoplay=1'` but that did not work.  Anyway, any help would be much appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another working solution that doesn't require a unique ID:

```
$(".vimeo").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'overlayShow'   : true,
        'overlayOpacity': .85,
        'overlayColor'  : '#000',
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 680,
        'height'        : 393,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1')+'&amp;autoplay=1',
        'type'          : 'swf'
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
'swf' : {'allowfullscreen':'true', 'autoplay':'1'}
```

Comment: Tried this but its not working.  Also tried appending the href call to 
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1' + '&autoplay=1'),

I think fancybox is just having trouble parsing the url with added autoplay on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way you can do it. Add a unike ID to eatch of your links and set the call for them as this

`$("a.video").click(function() {

    var video_fancybox = {

        'padding' : 0,

        'autoScale' : false,

        'transitionIn' : 'none',

        'transitionOut' : 'none',

        'title' : this.title,

        'width' : 400,

        'height' : 265,

        'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1'),

        'type' : 'swf',

        'swf'  : {

            'wmode' : 'transparent',

            'allowfullscreen' : 'true'

        }

    };

$("#vimeo_test3").fancybox( // On for eatch link

    $.extend(video_fancybox, {'href' : 'http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=3979490&amp;fullscreen=1'})

);

return false;

});`

Comment: Link will look like `<a class="video" id="vimeo_test3" href="http://vimeo.com/9532951">link 1</a>` Rember to have the same video id in the **$.extend(video_fancybox** line

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to replace "autoplay" with "autostart" and set it to "true".
Flash players don't understand "autoplay" as a command.
Code will be like this:

```
    $('#vimeo_video').click(function(){
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : true,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'         : 790,
        'height'        : 450,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1')+'&amp;autoplay=true',
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : { 'wmode' : 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen' : 'true', 'autostart' : 'true' }
    });
    return false;
});

$("#vimeo_video").trigger('click');
```